# pandas dataframe, resample rows in 1hour/60 minutes group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panda DataFrame that looks like this (time precision in seconds,
each row represents an event

```
index   date_and_time           value
103819  2023-12-31 16:34:17     1
103820  2023-12-31 16:34:41     1
103821  2023-12-31 16:37:29     1
103822  2023-12-31 16:39:33     1
103823  2023-12-31 16:39:59     1
103824  2023-12-31 16:40:40     1
103825  2023-12-31 16:41:36     1
103826  2023-12-31 16:42:56     1
103827  2023-12-31 16:43:24     1
103828  2023-12-31 16:43:56     1
```

I would like to resample it/do groupby so that events in x minute window
(say 60 minutes'1 hour) are grouped together and the 'value' variable for
resampled rows are summed, like

```
index   date_and_time   value
2023-12-31 16:00:00     6
2023-12-31 17:00:00     9
2023-12-31 18:00:00     12
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired result, you can use the `resample` function in pandas. Here's an example code to implement it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("df.csv")

# Convert 'date_and_time' column to datetime dtype
df['date_and_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_and_time'])

# Set 'date_and_time' as the index
df = df.set_index('date_and_time')

# Resample and sum the 'value' column in 10-minute intervals
df_resampled = df.resample('10min').sum(numeric_only=True)

# Reset the index and rename the columns
df_resampled = df_resampled.reset_index()
df_resampled.columns = ['date_and_time', 'value']

print(df_resampled)
```

This code converts the `date_and_time` column to a datetime data type and sets it as the index. Then, it uses the resample function with a frequency of `10min` to group the data into 10-minute intervals (use `1H` for 1-hour interval). Finally, it sums the `value` column and resets the index to get the desired result.

**df.csv:**

```
index,date_and_time,value
103819,2023-12-31,16:34:17,1
103820,2023-12-31,16:34:41,1
103821,2023-12-31,16:37:29,1
103822,2023-12-31,16:39:33,1
103823,2023-12-31,16:39:59,1
103824,2023-12-31,16:40:40,1
103825,2023-12-31,16:41:36,1
103826,2023-12-31,16:42:56,1
103827,2023-12-31,16:43:24,1
103828,2023-12-31,16:43:56,1
```

**output:**

```
        date_and_time  value
0 2024-01-24 16:30:00      5
1 2024-01-24 16:40:00      5
```

**NOTICE**: The default value of `numeric_only` in `DataFrameGroupBy.sum` is deprecated and in a future version of pandas, numeric_only will default to False. Therefore, remember to specify `numeric_only` as `True`